# How to use $_SERVER, $_POST and $_GET in .tpl

Tags: php, smarty

I have a `.tpl` file which contain form data which contain both add and edit functionality. I want to check whether user coming for `ADD` or for `EDIT` for that I need to check query string. 
For that I want to used `$_SERVER`, `$_POST` and `$_GET` array variables into .tpl file.

I am using directly like this but not working :

```
{$_SERVER}
{if $step_info->actions eq ""}        
        <tr>            
            <td><textArea name="step_details[]"></textArea></td>
            <td><textArea name="expected_results[]"></textArea></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <select onchange="content_modified = true"  name="etype[]">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1" label="Manual">Manual</option>
                    <option value="2" label="Automated">Automated</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {/if}
```

I am newbie in smarty and dont know much about it.

Need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use {$smarty.get.variable}

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

Comment: This solution worked for me. But just to add some extra details to this. As I am new to {smarty}, you need to write $smarty and not your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can access woth some resered words like following example

```
{* display the variable "page" from a form ($_POST['page']) *}

{$smarty.post.page}`
```

this [link](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty) may help you.